# New laptop and problem with external monitor on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, external-monitor

I got new tuxedo laptop. Everything seems to be working fine besides external monitor.
Monitor and cable works just fine. I tested that on old laptop.

Here weird behaviour starts. When I turn **on** monitor xrandr says:

```
HDMI 1-1 disconnected (...)
```

In ubuntu settings I cannot see options for external monitor.

But when I turn it **off**, screen flickers for a sec like it is adjusting and xrandr sees monitor:

```
HDMI-1-1 connected 1920x1080+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
```

And I also have option to clone or extend monitor.

Anyone idea what is going on?